# fuzzy string matching with grep

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to match rows in a file containing a string say `ACTGGGTAAACTA`. If 
I do

```
grep "ACTGGGTAAACTA" file
```

It gives me rows which have exact matches. Is there a way to allow for certain number of mismatches (substitutions, insertions or deletions)? For example, I am looking for sequences

1. Up to 3 allowed subtitutions like "AGTGGGTAACCAA" etc.
2. Insertions/deletions (having a partial match like "ACTGGGAAAATAAACTA" or "ACTAAACTA")

Comment: Do you mean something like "find ACTGGGTAAACTA or sequences that changes up to 3 letters"?

Comment: Regex is not a fuzzy-match tool. You have to be very precise about what, exactly, you are looking for. You can explicitly declare that some character can be missing (for example, `ACTGGGTA{1,3}CTA` makes it possible to match `ACTGGGTACTA`, `ACTGGGTAACTA` and `ACTGGGTAAACTA`), but the more "fuzzy" you make your regex, the more undesired matches you'll end up with.

Comment: Maybe similar to [Fuzzy file search in linux console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439121/fuzzy-file-search-in-linux-console)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fuzzy regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155840/fuzzy-regular-expressions)

Comment: No, have a look at [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Since this is clearly about DNA sequences, and is basically a solved problem in that context, why not just install BLAST locally? e.g. https://www.biostars.org/p/266983/#442757

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a tool called `agrep` for fuzzy regex matching, but it got abandoned.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep has a bit of history and links to related tools.

https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep looks like a revived open source release, but I have not tested it.

Failing that, see if you can find `tre-agrep` for your distro.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tre-agrep` and specify the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) with the `-E` switch. For example if you have a file `foo`:

```
cat <<EOF > foo
ACTGGGAAAATAAACTA
ACTAAACTA
ACTGGGTAAACTA
EOF
```

You can match every line with an edit distance of up to 9 like this:

```
tre-agrep -s -9 -w ACTGGGTAAACTA foo
```

Output:

```
4:ACTGGGAAAATAAACTA
4:ACTAAACTA
0:ACTGGGTAAACTA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to fuzzy-search for a string in the lines of a file as follows:

```bash
cat file | fzf --filter='ACTGGGTAAACTA'
```

The following will also work since you are redirecting the file to STDIN and `fzf` reads from it.

```bash
fzf --filter='ACTGGGTAAACTA' < file
```

In fact, you can also interactively see how `fzf` is filtering lines by launching its user interface as follows:

```bash
cat file | fzf
```

In the user interface, type some keywords(separated by spaces) to see filtering in action.

Remember the [GNU/Linux philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), specifically the modularity concept, which enable us to handle small-but-powerful pieces independently. We can gather a bunch of these small pieces to make magic. That is beauty of GNU/Linux

Comment: Probably avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Python library called [fuzzysearch](https://github.com/taleinat/fuzzysearch) (that I wrote) which provides precisely the required functionality.

Here's some sample code that should work:

```py
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

# 1. search allowing up to 3 substitutions
matches = find_near_matches("ACTGGGTAAACTA", data, max_substitutions=3)

# 2. also allow insertions and deletions, i.e. allow an edit distance
#    a.k.a. Levenshtein distance of up to 3
matches = find_near_matches("ACTGGGTAAACTA", data, max_l_dist=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: no.

**Long answer**: As [@JDB said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355972/string-matching-with-grep#comment48804315_30355972), regex is inherently precise. You can manually add in mismatches like `[ATGC]` instead of `A` in some spot, but there is no way to only allow a small amount of any mismatches. I suggest that you write your own code to parse it, or try to find a DNA parser somewhere.