# match words with few differences allowed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, terminal, similarity

I was wondering is there is any tool to match *almost* the same word for a bash terminal.

In the following file, called **list.txt** contain 1 word per line:

```
ban
1ban
12ban
12ban3
```

It is easy to find words containing "ban"

```
grep -E "*ban*" list.txt
```

Question:

How to actually match words that are have x letters differences?
With the search word "ban", I expect the match "1ban" for X=1.

Concerning the notion of distance, I want to have maximum:
X deletion 
or X substitutions 
or X insertions

Any tool, but preferentially something you could call as command-line on a bash terminal.

NOTE: The Levenshtein Distance will count an insertion of 2 letter as 1 difference. This is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe you want `grep "[a-z]anana" list.txt`? Or even `grep "[^[:space:]]anana" list.txt`. Probably, your answer is [already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355972/fuzzy-string-matching-with-grep).

Comment: Try https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: If Python comes into play, you may use the PyPi regex package and use fuzzy matching combined with regex functionality.

Comment: You are poviding some solution to an unknown set of requirements. This is not a good idea because without exact requirements, all solutions are considered good and wrong - please update the question with a real set of requirements. Are you searching whole words or not? What edits do you want to consider? Just substitutions without insertions/deletions? Please make the question answerable.

Comment: True, I actually understand why it is hard to answer this question. The notion of distance can be interpreted on different way. I am looking for whole words, and I actually want to have maximum X difference (so 1 deletion OR 1 substitution OR 1 deletion). Can you update your answer?

Comment: I have updated my solution and tested it a bit, it seems working as per the current requirements. Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Python [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) class that supports fuzzy matching.

Since you actually want to match words with maximum *X* difference (1 deletion OR 1 substitution OR 1 deletion), you may create a Python script like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import regex, io, sys

def main(argv):
        if len(argv) < 3:
                # print("USAGE: fuzzy_search -searchword -xdiff -file")
                exit(-1)
        search=argv[0]
        xdiff=argv[1]
        file=argv[2]
        # print("Searching for {} in {} with {} differences...".format(search, file, xdiff))
        with open(file, "r") as f:
                contents = f.read()
                print(regex.findall(r"\b(?:{0}){{s<={1},i<={1},d<={1}}}\b".format(regex.escape(search), xdiff), contents))

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Here, `{s<=1,i<=1,d<=1}` means we allow the word we search for 1 or 0 substitutions (`s<=1`), 1 or 0 insertions (`i<=1`) or 1 or 0 deletions (`d<=1`).

The `\b` are *word boundaries*, thanks to that construct, only whole words are matched (no `cat` in `vacation` will get matched).

Save as `fuzzy_search.py`.

Then, you may call it as

```
python3 fuzzy_search.py "ban" 1 file
```

where `"ban"` is the word the fuzzy search is being performed for and `1` is the higher limit of differences.

The result I get is

```
['ban', '1ban']
```

You may change the format of the output to line only:

```
print("\n".join(regex.findall(r"\b(?:{0}){{s<={1},i<={1},d<={1}}}\b".format(regex.escape(search), xdiff), contents)))
```

Then, the result is

```
ban
1ban
```

Comment: Thanks you! This seem like doing the job... except that I cannot use it to search for x differences (let say if you allow 2 difference instead of 1). It is apparently not getting rid of the end of line char. Using f.readline().strip(), I can loop on each line, but then something is wrong with the regexp. Could you explain me a bit more your expression?

Comment: @Gildas If you need to allow no more than 2 substitutions, replace `s<=1` with `s<=2`. You may also use a variable here to be passed via command line. What do you mean by end of line? You may `.strip()` it. See [the PyPi regex docs](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) for more examples. `{0<s<4}` will allow 0, 1, 2 or 3 substituitons. `s`, `d`, `i` are types of difference, and you may easily control that with the quantifier.

Comment: @Gildas Please update your question to be more  specific about what you want. My current answer gives you a jumpstart.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I am still doing some tests on your answer. I created a variable X that I pass to the regular expression r"(?:{}){{s<=X,i<=X,d<=X,e<=X}}".format(regex.escape(search.strip() ), but so far it is not doing what I expect. I will update the question, but did you try it? the regular expression is not clear for me, and return a partial match of a word.

Comment: @Gildas Exactly. If you plan to match whole words, use a word boundary ,`\b`, on both ends, `r"\b(?:{0}){{s<={1},i<={1},d<={1},e<={1}}}\b".format(regex.escape(search), threshold)` (where `threshold` is the limit of the differences). If you do not want to allow deletions, remove `,d<={1}`.

Comment: Using banana can be misleading, so I changed for "ban". I hope the question/ requirements are now easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the difference as shown below by checking each character using python,

```
def is_diff(str1, str2):
    diff = False
    for char1, char2 in zip(str1, str2):
        if char1 != char2:
            if diff:
                return False
            else:
                diff = True
    return diff
with open('list.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    print is_diff('ban', line)
```